# Linked Lists C - after adding nodes print only the last value

Tags: c, linked-list

After reading here about linked lists I started messing with it, I defined struct, inserted to it, but faced with something I dont understand, maybe I did something wrong but I think I need your advice or small enlightenment.

Here is my code:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};

typedef struct node item;

item printcurr(item *curr){
    printf("curr -> val %d\n",curr->val);
}

item addnode(item *curr,item *head,int num){
    curr->val=num;
    curr->next = head;
    head=curr;
}

void main() {
    item * curr, * head;
    int i,ITEMS,num;

    head = NULL;
    printf("How many items? \n");
    scanf("%d",&ITEMS);
    printf("Insert your numbers please\n");
    for(i=1;i<=ITEMS;i++) {
        curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
        scanf("%d",&num);
        addnode(curr,head,num);
    }

    while(curr) {
        printcurr(curr);
        curr = curr->next ;
    }
}
```

For example, I get the number of ITEM 3, then I insert 1,2,3 and the output will be 3. I am missing something here; how I will print all the list and not only the last number?

Comment: Please format your code a little more cleanly. It helps if you only use tabs or spaces, not both mixed together.

Comment: `main` should return `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in addnote().  The value of head inside main() is never changed because only the local version of head inside addnode() is modified.  (As a side note: addnote() should return void.)

Instead use

```
void addnode(item *curr, item **head, int num) {
    curr->val  = num;
    curr->next = *head;
    *head = curr;
}
...
addnode(curr, &head, num);
```

Alternative version:

```
void addnode(item *curr, item *head, int num) {
    curr->val  = num;
    curr->next = *head;
}
...
addnode(curr, head, num);
head = curr;
```

Comment: I was just typing this answer.  +1.  You also need to take @Codeguru's answer into account.

Comment: I disagree with @Code-Guru. The way the code is laid out, curr actually is the head of the list. There's nothing wrong with the printing code. The problem lies in addnode() and only there. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: what I`m understand from it is that I need to change the head outside the function, what I need to change in my function to do it?

Comment: It's explained above. But I'll create an alternative version.

Comment: ok, I saw your last edit, I want to understand what you did, & is the address of head , so what the difference if I point on him? and than in the function get head with (**) what it giving to me this operator?

Comment: Speaking from the perspective of main(), head is a pointer to an item. When this pointer is passed to addnote(), the addnote() function receives a _copy_ of the pointer, just as it receives a copy of the int. Thus, changing the copy of the pointer inside addnote() does not change its value in the calling function. However, the _item the pointer points to_ is not copied and changes to it will be effective.
Therefore, I've changed head to be the pointer to a pointer to an item, which allows the pointer to item to be changed.

Comment: @ThiemoNagel That is very likely. I didn't take the time to analyze what the actual value of `curr` is before the `while` loop starts for printing. The main point of my answer is that `curr`'s value is not obvious at this point in the code.

Comment: OK Thanks, one more thing, why its printing to me in reverse order? why its LIFO? if we set the curr to be @ start again? how I will force it to be printed at the order I inserted?

Comment: It's reversed because you're inserting at the head. You'll have to insert at the tail to preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the loop that does the printing:

```
while(curr) {

  printcurr(curr);
  curr = curr->next ;
}
```

Note that this assumes that `curr` points to a node. You have not told where `curr` should start. Based on your description, `curr` points at the last node in the list, so this is the only one that gets printed out. You need to set `curr` to start at the `head`.

Also, I suggest that separate this into its own function. It will make your code much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I created function thats get head and curr, I set curr=head and tried to print the values of the list and nothing.

Comment: @OfirAttia Please edit your original question with your new code. Also include an example of the input and output.